# Setting a readonly property of a class for unit testing

Tags: c#, unit-testing, readonly, nsubstitute

I have an interface like this

```
public interface IConnection
{
    Strategy Gc { get; }

    bool IsConnected();

    bool Connect();
}
```

I want to unit test methods of a class that uses this interface. Now I want to set Gc but it happens to be readonly. Is there a way to set Gc field without making changes to this interface class?
I am using MS fakes and Nsubstitute for unit testing. However, apparently none provides a solution. `PrivateObject` does not work either.

Changing Interface is not an option. Suggest better solutions.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

With `NSubstitute`it is quite easy. First create a mock for your interface:

```
var mock = Substitute.For<IConnection>();
```

Now you can mock the member by setting any return-type for the property:

```
mock.Gc.Returns(Substitute.For<Strategy>());
```

Finally provide that mocked instance as parameter to the service depending on that instance, for example:

```
var target = new MyClassToTest();
target.DoSomething(mock);  // mock is an instance of IConnection
```

Now whenever your method is called it returns a dumm-instance for `Strategy`. Of course you can also set any other arbitrary return-type within the `Returns`-statement. Just have a look at http://nsubstitute.github.io/help/set-return-value for further information.

Comment: It worked, thanks. Am scratching my head how on earth I didn't try that.